# Is there a better and safer way than using: #define DEBUG?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In one of my asp.Net pages I want to set some properties of a user control so that it behaves differently to make things easier and faster while I debug and test my page.

I want to compile the code block where I set my properties only if I am running the VS in DEBUG. I know I can use conditional compiling directives like:

```
#define DEBUG

#if DEBUG
        // some settings here
#else
              // some settings to be used in Released code
#endif
```

But the thing is I want to save myself from the risk of commenting out the define declaration.

Is there a safer way than this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't generally include the `#define` in your code - the point of having different Visual Studio project configurations is that *they* control what preprocessor symbols are defined.

Just build the Release or Debug configuration to control which bit of code is used.

Answer (score -2):

You did wrong in your code. You will never run in the `#else` section because you always define the `DEBUG` symbol, so it has no sense to define the if when it's always true.

About safety, I see no threats in using `#define DEBUG`. Just remove it and use project configurations!